# Separating a sum of time-shifted signals

Tags: source-separation

Let us suppose that I measure, with an instrument, $h(t,\delta)=f(t)+g(t+\delta)$, where $f(t)$ is the desired signal, and $g(t)$ corresponds to some added undesirable corruption to $h(t,\delta)$. In practice, $t$ is discrete and corresponds to evenly spaced samples. We're allowed to measure $h(t,\delta)$, practically, for 10s of $\delta$s, which we can pick arbitrarily.

One non-robust solution is we take $\partial_\delta h(t,\delta)$, take $\delta$ to zero, and integrate to get $g$, and then subtract this off. This is, obviously, not numerically robust. Is there a numerically robust version of this?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! It's not clear: are you saying that you can choose $\delta$? Do you know that $f(t)$ or $g(t)$ looks like?

Comment: Yes, $\delta$ may be chosen arbitrarily. I don't know what f(t) or g(t) looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $g(t)$ is relatively uncorrelated with itself you can average over as many $\delta$ as is feasible. The more you average, the more you remove $g(t)$

Comment: I want to assume nothing about g(t). It's quite correlated with itself, in fact, and not periodic.